# Printing prn file in window service

Tags: c#, service, window

I am unable to print prn file on network printer from .Net window Service.
I use File.Copy method but it does not work. I use cmd.exe through Process.Start method but it does not work. But If I copy the same code in windows form application then it works fine. Can anybody help me.

Comment: Code please... that question is vague...we are here to help, so please publish a code sample that fits your question. We are not mind-readers...show us exactly what you did....

Answer (score 0):

The problem was service was running under different system account and that printer was not configured for that user.